# How do you convert a 32bit RGB png with encoded height values to 16 bit png using browser side javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, heightmap

I am trying to create a 16bit heightmap png from a 32bit Rgb encoded height value png.

According to [mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/) I can decode their png pixel values to height values in meters with this formula.    `height = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1)`

I am new to understanding this type of information and have tried to figure it out myself but I need some help.

I found this program called [image-js](https://github.com/image-js/image-js),   docs for this program are [here](https://image-js.github.io/image-js/) .  Note I am using this in the browser not with node.

I think it has the abilities that I need. However, I am really not sure how to get the data from the original image and create a new 16bit png with the new height values calculated from the above formula.

If you look in the docs under image I can set many properties such as

bitDepth and set that to 16

getPixelsArray() this function will give me an array of pixels values in the form of r,g,b.  I think I can then run each pixel through the above formula to get the height.  After that how do I turn this height data back into a 16bit grayscale heightmap png?

Thanks!

Example images.
32bit Rgb encoded height value png
[image]

16 bit heightmap png.  You have to zoom in to see the image changes
[image]

**Update:**

Thanks to traktor for the suggestion.  I wanted to add some information to my question.

I don't necessarily need to use image-js.  My main goal is to get a 16 bit heightmap from a 32 bit RGB.  So any other browser side javscript method would be fine.  I also am using browser side createWritable(); stream to write file to disk.

I have a method used from this nice module https://github.com/colkassad/terrain-rgb-height however I cannot get the browser side version of pngjs to work correctly.  I think there is a difference between browser side stream reader/writers and node reader/writers that make it not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the source  code for `Image-js` package on GitHub turns up that the `options` object used in calls to the library is verified in source file [`kind.js`](https://github.com/image-js/image-js/blob/93d3cce18279cf1efe82a0e39f288d2276036959/src/image/core/kind.js#L64) which enumerates supported options properties in the assignment statement:

```
const { components, alpha, bitDepth, colorModel } = definition;
```

However, many options are defaulted using `kind` option property,  which itself defaults to "RGBA".

Knowing more about option properties allows using them (I couldn't find options documentation outside of the code).

I would suggest

1. Create an Image-js image from the 32bit encoded height png. Omit a `kind` property to use the default 32bit PNG pixel model of 3 color channels plus one alpha channel.
2. Convert the image data (held as a typed array in the image object's [`data`](https://image-js.github.io/image-js/#imagedata) property) to a *single dimensional array* of height values using the MapBox conversion algorithm. The layout of the (`image.data`) typed array appears to be the same as that used for [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData)
3. Create a new image-js image using

   ```
   new Image(width, height, decodedHeightArray, {kind="GREY", bitDepth:16})
   ```

   where `decodedHeightArray` is the array prepared in the previous step.

Just adding my code to what tracktor's answer provided
Thank you very much traktor

This worked perfectly.  For anyone who wants the code

I am using [image-js](https://github.com/image-js/image-js) to encode and decode the image

```
 let file_handleSixteen = await dir_handle.getFileHandle(sixteen_file_name, {create: true})

 let writableSixteen = await file_handleSixteen.createWritable();


async function convert16(arrayBuff) {

  let image = await Image.load(arrayBuff);

  let width = image.width
  let height = image.height

  let decodedHeightArray = []
  let pixelsArray = image.getPixelsArray()
  for (const pixel of pixelsArray) {
    let r = pixel[0]
    let g = pixel[1]
    let b = pixel[2]
    let height = getHeightFromRgb(r, g, b);
    decodedHeightArray.push(height)
  }
  let newImage = new Image(width, height, decodedHeightArray, {kind: "GREY", bitDepth: 16})
  return newImage.toBlob()
}

function getHeightFromRgb(r, g, b) {
  return -10000 + ((r * 256 * 256 + g * 256 + b) * 0.1);
}


  const file = await file_handleRgb.getFile();
  let imageBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
  let convertedArray = await convert16(imageBuffer)

 await writableSixteen.write(convertedArray)
 await writableSixteen.close();
```

I am also using the browser streams api to write the file to disk.  Note the filestreams writable.write only accepts certain values one of them being a Blob that is why converted it to Blob before passing it to the write method

---